# How do I shrink a HFS+ partition image?

Tags: linux-mint, partition, disk-image, hfs+

I recently installed Linux Mint on my laptop, but saved the original operating system (Mac OS) to a partition image. How do I shrink the image? It's 80GB, however the data in the image only takes up about 60GB.

Comment: Before I write an answer, why are you storing the OS image? Do you only care about your personal files that were on the installation, or are you planning on using the image to restore your system?

Comment: I just want access to all the files. I don't really care if it's bootable, since I'll never be reinstalling Mac OS on my computer.

Comment: How much free space do you have on your hard drive? If you have at least 60GB, we can use that space as a buffer.

Comment: I don't have enough free space to duplicate it. Only about 10GB. That's why I'm shrinking it. (I only have a 128GB internal hard drive).

Comment: Do you have an external hard drive or something similar that has at least 60GB? It would make the process much easier.

Comment: Actually, I found another method. Just to clarify, is the image an image of the entire disk, or just the hfs+ partition?

Comment: I used the Disks application in Linux Mint and clicked "Save Partition Image". So I think it's the partition.